# SQL-Procedures: NOT EXISTS seems to be always true

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello stackoverflow members.

First, I'm new to SQL and have almost only theory knowledge about databases. This is the table:

```
create table ACCOUNT (LOGIN varchar (16) primary key, MAIN boolean not null);
```

Now I have created this procedure for inserting a new tuple:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure add_account (in login varchar (16))
    begin
        declare main boolean;
        set main = not exists (select LOGIN from ACCOUNT where MAIN);
        insert into ACCOUNT (LOGIN, MAIN) values (login, main);
    end
$$
delimiter ;
```

My intention: By using `add_account`, only one tuple in `ACCOUNT` has the value `true` for attribute `MAIN`. But after that, it seems that the `NOT EXISTS` is always true:

```
call add_account ('First');
call add_account ('Second');
select * from ACCOUNT;
+--------+------+
| LOGIN  | MAIN |
+--------+------+
| First  |    1 |
| Second |    1 |
+--------+------+
```

The second should be 0 because there is already a tuple that is 1. Anyone got ideas? What is wrong about my code/thinking?

Thanks in advance and Greetings

---

After Gordon's answer, I renamed the lower-case `main` to `foo`. My wrong thinking: I thought that lower-case `main` would be seen as different from upper-case `MAIN`. Now the results are as I wished:

```
call add_account ('First');
call add_account ('Second');
select * from ACCOUNT;
+--------+------+
| LOGIN  | MAIN |
+--------+------+
| First  |    1 |
| Second |    0 |
+--------+------+
```

Comment: The syntax is clearly MySQL, so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain this logic, line by line:

1. `declare main boolean;`
2. `set main = not exists (select LOGIN from ACCOUNT where MAIN);`
3. `insert into ACCOUNT (LOGIN, MAIN) values (login, main);`

Line 1 declares a variable called `main` as a boolean.  By default, the value will be `NULL`, which is treated as false.

Line 2 runs the following query:

```
select LOGIN
from ACCOUNT
where MAIN
```

Well, `MAIN` is `NULL` -- basically "false" -- hence this returns no values.  So, the `NOT EXISTS` returns "true", which is then assigned to `main`

Line 3 inserts the new value in the row.

This is clearly not your intention.  I would suggest that you ask another question and describe what you want to do, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ah okay, just renaming the low-case `main` to something other does the "trick" (tested it - now the second value is 0). I thought it would be seen as different from the upper-case `MAIN`. I'll check this answer as right, I'm grateful for that.